# Giving time stamp in a report involving information in the past and projections for the future,

Tags: phrase-choice

Below are my three ideas for the Intro for this test, which asks you to summarize the main features of a graph and make comparisons where relevant. I don't know which way of giving the examined period sounds the best to native speakers' ears here. What is your personal preference?

1. The graph illustrates the percentage of citizens over the age of 65 in a collection of nations **from 1940 to 2020 and makes projections for 2040.**
2. The graph illustrates the percentage of citizens over the age of 65 in a collection of nations **from 1940 through projections to 2040.**
3. The graph illustrates the percentage of citizens over the age of 65 in a collection of nations **from 1940 to 2040.**

The third version is the simplest. However, it doesn't say anything about projections, that's why I proceeded to do research and come up with the first two versions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd be happy with either 1 or 3.

1 is explicit but rather wordy. 3 doesn't say that the data from 2020 are projections, but the intelligent reader will be able to work this out without being told it. It is a matter for to decide if you want to make the fact that the graph is based on projections from 2020.

Is that graph correct The World bank has a very different graph. Japan went ahead of the USA in 1989 and Sweden in 2000.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for responding. Well I'm just doing the test so it doesn't really matter if the data is incorrect ^^.

Comment: How can it not matter?

Comment: Oh it's the IELTS test. They only test my ability to report the main features of a given graph in English, not the validity of the figures.